# Creating Image Button programmatically in VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm new using VB so maybe someone can help me on my problem..
I'm able to create image button programmatically but I can't get the image ..
Code Below:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        ibtn = New ImageButton

        ibtn.ID = "1"
        ibtn.ImageUrl = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\red.png"
        Panel1.Controls.Add(ibtn)
    End Sub  
End Class
```

Advance Thanks! :)

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't get the image"?

Comment: @RoyDictus the image i specified in imageUrl is not showing when I the program is running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to use Physical image path because it can access only virtual path. You should use the **Server.MapPath**.

So in order to get this image, copy image into web project and use server.mappath as shown below :

```
ibtn.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("[Path]/1.jpg")
```